# TypeError: Cannot read property 'udp' of undefined

Tags: android, google-chrome, ionic-framework, udp

I need to write an ionic app that sends and recieves udp packets. i'm using this plugin for android:
https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp

this is my code in app.js:

```
    $scope.connect = function() {
      var socketId;

      // Handle the "onReceive" event.
      var onReceive = function(info) {
        if (info.socketId !== socketId)
        return;
        console.log(info.data);
};

// Create the Socket
chrome.sockets.udp.create({}, function(socketInfo) {
  socketId = socketInfo.socketId;
  // Setup event handler and bind socket.
  chrome.sockets.udp.onReceive.addListener(onReceive);
  chrome.sockets.udp.bind(socketId,
    "0.0.0.0", 55555, function(result) {
      if (result < 0) {
        console.log("Error binding socket.");
        return;
      }
      var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(20);
      var dv = new DataView(arrayBuffer,0);
      dv.setUint16(0,0);
      dv.setUint16(1,12);
      dv.setUint16(2,0);
      dv.setUint16(3,0);
      dv.setUint32(4,0);
      dv.setUint32(5,55555);
      dv.setUint32(6,0);
      console.log("here");
      chrome.sockets.udp.send(socketId, arrayBuffer,
        '127.0.0.1', 2222, function(sendInfo) {
          console.log("sent " + sendInfo.bytesSent);
      });
  });
});
}})
```

(this is the same example taken from here:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network (for udp)

i understand that i need to give this udp permissions in some kind of a manifest file, where exactly can i do that?
i have an android.jason file and an AndroidManifest.xml file.

thanks alot!

Comment: The problem was that i ran the ionic app with a cordova plugin specific for android. When i ran the app on my android device, it all worked just fine. There is no need to change any AndroidManifest.xml file.